# How to detect that grid rows have been created in a Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working with a Kendo UI `Grid` object (Javascript version) that gets loaded from an async call. Rows are created from row templates which define a number of buttons for each row - these are pure HTML `INPUT` elements - all code handling them is in separate Javascript files.

When the grid is created (that is all `TR` elements have been created in the DOM by the `Grid` control) I need to run through all the rows and attach event handlers to the various buttons and update a number of their properties. My problem is that I can't figure out when the DOM elements (the `TR`-s) are created by the grid. I tried using the `dataBound` event which is fired but the grid DOM isn't created yet - only the response data can be manipulated. I also tried the `detailInit` event but that's not fired (I'm not much surprised - the grid has no detail items).

I found [this Telerik forum](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/strait-forward-way-to-select-first-row-row-of-a-grid-after-a-refresh.aspx) where a Telerik rep suggests using `setTimeout()` to poll if the elements exist in the DOM. I find it hard to believe that this questionable solution is the only approach to something that should be build into the grid as a callback.

So my question is, is there a reliable way to detect when the grid DOM is ready after a refresh? Or, alternatively, is there a way to detect as each `TR` element is created (one by one)?

**Edit**

Added code:

```
var oDataSource =
{
    type : "odata",
    error : function ( oEvent )
    {
        // show error
    },
    transport :
    {
        read :
        {
            url : "http://url.com/...",
            dataType : "json"
        }
    },
    schema :
    {
        data : function ( oData )
        {
            return ( oData["value"] );
        },
        total : function ( oData )
        {
            return ( oData["odata.count"] );
        },
        model :
        {
            fields :
            {
                /* Model definition */
            }
        },
        pageSize : 15,
        serverPaging : true,
        serverFiltering : true,
        serverSorting : true
    }
};

var oGridSettings =
{
    dataSource : oDataSource,
    rowTemplate : kendo.template ( $( "#detail-row-template" ).html () ),
    sortable : true,
    pageable : true,
    columns :
    [
        /* Column definitions */
    ]
};

oDiv.kendoGrid ( oGridSettings );
```

Comment: Can you add the code with the async call and the grid creation to your question?

Comment: as far as I can see, the DataBound event is triggered after updating the DOM; there is a DataBinding event which is triggered before the DOM is changed; how do you determine that the DOM isn't ready in dataBound?

Comment: @LarsHöppner You're right - the DOM is ready. I got misled by none of the new DOM elements being visible. <facepalm /> I had a bug in the code and in the debugger it failed to pick up the items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the kendo documentation

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.read

> The data source uses jQuery.ajax to make a HTTP request to the remote
>   service. The value configured via transport.read is passed to
>   jQuery.ajax. This means that you can set all options supported by
>   jQuery.ajax via transport.read except the success and error callback
>   functions which are used by the transport.

So you could add a `complete` callback function to the dataSource's `transport.read` function, like this:

```
transport :
{
    read :
    {
        url : "http://url.com/...",
        dataType : "json",
        complete: function(data, status) {
            if (status === "success") {
                // your code that will be executed once the request is done
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is that different from using the grid's `dataBound` event handler? Hooking the Ajax call will still only give me the response data, not the DOM elements that the grid creates. Plus this way I'd have to build the OData URL which the grid does otherwise - that's somewhat complex if the grid has sorting / paging / filtering.

Comment: The `complete` callback happens after the `success` callback (which Kendo uses) is done. By the time the `success` callback is done, the elements that form the grid should already be in the DOM.

Comment: I haven't tried `complete` specifically but as I said, running the Ajax call directly bypasses the grid's code to generate the correct OData URL. Since there's no way to get the URL from the grid, I can't do this - the OData URL is a complex URL with a number of parameters (formed by the grid from the base URL).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The `complete` function doesn't bypass the grid's original code, it's just another property of the transport.read object (which translates to a jQuery.ajax parameter internally). All it does is execute code after the ajax request and the internal success callback (where Kendo places the rows in the DOM) are done.

Comment: It doesn't, but see the text I quoted from the Kendo documentation. You can use any options that are normally used in `jQuery.ajax()` except for `success` and `error`, which Kendo uses internally. You only see `url` and `dataType` as examples, but if you check the jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, those are valid `jQuery.ajax()` options as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that little tidbit in the documentation. As it turns out, even after `dataBound` the DOM is available but none of it is visible at the time. My code also had a bug - all these together misled me.